# unable to get specific version of key-value from Hashicorp Vault

Tags: get, version, key-value, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/secrets-management/versioned-kv

I'm referring to hashicorp documentation above to read a specific version of key-value from the vault.

Step 3: Retrieve a specific version of the secret

```
curl --header "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" \
      $VAULT_ADDR/v1/secret/data/customer/acme\?version=1 | jq -r ".data"
```

which in my case translates to:

```
C:\Users\meuser>curl --header "X-Vault-Token: s.r8JA4TzlDd8Ps8GtCnmolSHJ" -H "X-Vault-Namespace: vault-poc/" https://eng-mybank.com/v1/kv/data/tool-common/dev\?version=1  | jq -r ".data"
```

Output:

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
> Current
>
> ```
>                              Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
> ```
>
> 100    14  100    14    0     0     10      0  0:00:01  0:00:01
> --:--:--    10
>
> null

As you can see instead of returning version 1 of the key-value I get `null`

The 4 versions of key-value exist and is also evident from the UI snapshot below:

[image]

If I simply remove `/?version=4` I get the latest version 4 key-value pair as below.

```
C:\Users\meuser>curl --header "X-Vault-Token: s.r8JA4TzlDd8Ps8GtCnmolSHJ" -H "X-Vault-Namespace: vault-poc/" https://eng-mybank.com/v1/kv/data/tool-common/dev  | jq -r ".data"
```

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
> Current
>
> ```
>                              Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
> ```
>
> 100   358  100   358    0     0    246      0  0:00:01  0:00:01
> --:--:--   247
>
> {
>
> "data": {
>
> ```
> "mykey1": "myvalue1",
>
> "mykey2": "myvalue2",
>
> "mykey3": "myvalue3",
>
> "mykey4": "myvalue4"
> ```
>
> },
>
> "metadata": {
>
> ```
> "created_time": "2023-06-06T18:21:49.815786014Z",
>
> "deletion_time": "",
>
> "destroyed": false,
>
> "version": 4
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

Can you please suggest how can I get a specific version of key-value?

I would also like all the versions of the key-values to be displayed. If it is possible please suggest how?

Comment: This appears to be a typo in the API endpoint where the `?` character is being escaped for some reason despite no string interpolation. Remove the `\` escape typo from the API endpoint specifying the version, and it should work.

Comment: @MattSchuchard it worked `C:\Users\meuser>curl --header "X-Vault-Token: s.r8JA4TzlDd8Ps8GtCnmolSHJ" -H "X-Vault-Namespace: vault-poc/" https://eng-mybank.com/v1/kv/data/tool-common/dev?version=1  | jq -r ".data"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API endpoint should be updated to not include the escape character `\` for the specified version `?version=1`:

```
C:\Users\meuser>curl --header "X-Vault-Token: s.r8JA4TzlDd8Ps8GtCnmolSHJ" -H "X-Vault-Namespace: vault-poc/" https://eng-mybank.com/v1/kv/data/tool-common/dev?version=1  | jq -r ".data"
```

That should GET the response from the Vault API for the specified secret version.